# hp stream 11 wifi works after reboot but disconnects after sleep and won't reconnect

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager, suspend

I have a new HP Stream 11 with rtl8723be driver (lwfinger version with antenna select) with Linux Mint 17.3 (ubuntu 14.04) installed in place of win10.

Wifi works after reboot, and works fine while I'm using it.  If it sleeps (or hibernates) the wifi won't reconnect afterwards no matter what I do (I've gone as far as `nmcli nm wifi off`, `modprobe -rv rtl8723be cfg80211` & `modprobe -v rtl8723be cfg80211`, `/etc/init.d/networking restart` & `nmcli nm wifi on`).

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf 
options rtl8723be ant_sel=2 msi=1 swenc=0 fwlps=0 swlps=0 ips=0
```

relevant log:

```
Jun 16 19:24:34 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'xxxxxx_Wireless'.
    Jun 16 19:24:34 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0) starting connection 'xxxxxx_Wireless'
    Jun 16 19:24:34 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
    Jun 16 19:24:34 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
    Jun 16 19:24:34 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
    Jun 16 19:24:34 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
    Jun 16 19:24:34 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
    Jun 16 19:24:34 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
    Jun 16 19:24:34 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
    Jun 16 19:24:34 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
    Jun 16 19:24:34 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): access point 'xxxxxx_Wireless' has security, but secrets are required.
    Jun 16 19:24:34 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
    Jun 16 19:24:34 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
    Jun 16 19:24:34 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
    Jun 16 19:24:34 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
    Jun 16 19:24:34 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
    Jun 16 19:24:34 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
    Jun 16 19:24:34 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
    Jun 16 19:24:34 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
    Jun 16 19:24:34 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
    Jun 16 19:24:34 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): connection 'xxxxxx_Wireless' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
    Jun 16 19:24:34 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Config: added 'ssid' value 'xxxxxx_Wireless'
    Jun 16 19:24:34 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
    Jun 16 19:24:34 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
    Jun 16 19:24:34 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
    Jun 16 19:24:34 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
    Jun 16 19:24:34 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
    Jun 16 19:24:34 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
    Jun 16 19:24:59 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <warn> Activation (wlan0/wireless): association took too long, failing activation.
    Jun 16 19:24:59 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> failed (reason 'SSID not found') [50 120 53]
    Jun 16 19:24:59 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
    Jun 16 19:24:59 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed for connection 'xxxxxx_Wireless'
    Jun 16 19:24:59 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
    Jun 16 19:24:59 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
    Jun 16 19:24:59 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
    Jun 16 19:24:59 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <warn> Couldn't disconnect supplicant interface: This interface is not connected.
    Jun 16 19:25:02 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'xxxxxx_Wireless'.
    Jun 16 19:25:02 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0) starting connection 'xxxxxx_Wireless'
    Jun 16 19:25:02 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
    Jun 16 19:25:02 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
    Jun 16 19:25:02 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
    Jun 16 19:25:02 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
    Jun 16 19:25:02 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
    Jun 16 19:25:02 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
    Jun 16 19:25:02 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
    Jun 16 19:25:02 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
    Jun 16 19:25:02 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): access point 'xxxxxx_Wireless' has security, but secrets are required.
    Jun 16 19:25:02 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
    Jun 16 19:25:02 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
    Jun 16 19:25:02 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
    Jun 16 19:25:02 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
    Jun 16 19:25:02 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
    Jun 16 19:25:02 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
    Jun 16 19:25:02 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
    Jun 16 19:25:02 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
    Jun 16 19:25:02 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
    Jun 16 19:25:02 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): connection 'xxxxxx_Wireless' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
    Jun 16 19:25:02 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Config: added 'ssid' value 'xxxxxx_Wireless'
    Jun 16 19:25:02 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
    Jun 16 19:25:02 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
    Jun 16 19:25:02 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
    Jun 16 19:25:02 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
    Jun 16 19:25:02 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
    Jun 16 19:25:02 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
    Jun 16 19:25:27 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <warn> Activation (wlan0/wireless): association took too long, failing activation.
    Jun 16 19:25:27 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> failed (reason 'SSID not found') [50 120 53]
    Jun 16 19:25:27 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
    Jun 16 19:25:27 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> Marking connection 'xxxxxx_Wireless' invalid.
    Jun 16 19:25:27 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed for connection 'xxxxxx_Wireless'
    Jun 16 19:25:27 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
    Jun 16 19:25:27 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
    Jun 16 19:25:27 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
    Jun 16 19:25:27 xxxxxx NetworkManager[9759]: <warn> Couldn't disconnect supplicant interface: This interface is not connected.

$ egrep  '.*' /sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/*
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/ant_sel:2
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/debug:1
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/disable_watchdog:N
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/fwlps:N
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/ips:N
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/msi:Y
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/swenc:N
/sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/swlps:N
```

What debug info can I supply to help trace the problem?
Any suggestions for what to try next?

Thanks

Comment: even if does not solve the problem, a way to mitigate maybe could be `sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that and it didn't change anything. :-(

Answer (score 0):

wicd seems to provide a stable connection, after 24 hours use.

I also added the rtl8723be module to `/etc/pm/config.d/modules` line `SUSPEND_MODULES="uhci_hd button ehci_hd rtl8723be"` as unloading & reloading the wifi module around sleep is recommended if you use pm_utils (ubuntu does) and there are problems.  See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pm-utils#Standby.2Fsuspend_to_RAM